# Multiple Library Projects in Android

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-play-services

Can we use two library projects in android? I want to use **map_lib** and **google_play-services-lib** in my android project. **map_lib** for displaying the Google Map in my app and **google_play-services-lib** for getting GPS values to track the user. If i add both the Library projects in my app, my **R.java** file is missing. I know we can do both tasks using **map_lib**. But i want to use it seprately.

Kindly help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you certainly can, make sure you have imported the projects in your workspace and added them to the build path,then clean your project and restart eclipse.

Comment: Thanks KKGanguly. How to do this. Can u explain me??

Comment: You have to first import your projects from to your workspace by file-> import, then go to build path -> configure build path and add both the jars, then go to project-> clean project,make sure build automatically is selected.then restart eclipse.Also be careful that there is no error in your xml files or java files,if there are any error,R.java wont generate.So first clean any error,and then clean project and restart.Your R.java will be back again

Comment: When i added the second jar file my R.java file is missing. By Cleanind and restarting the eclipse the R.java file ll be generated.

Comment: Its a dependency problem,then,I guess.
try this:
    Delete android-support-v4.jar from your project,
    Add the same file from Library project to your project

Comment: In my project, android-support-v4.jar is in 'Android Private Libraries' folder and 'Referenced Libraries' folder. From where i have to delete and from where i have to add.

Answer (score 0):

Check Console you get Jar mismatch.

add same android-support-v4.jar file in every project not int (Google-play-service).

You can add n numbers of libs.

STEPS:-
1)take any android-support-v4.jar file from your application project /library project.
2)paste android-support-v4.jar file in both project libs folder.
3)done.enjoy

Comment: Thanks Imtiyaz. Im getting that Jar mismatch. How to solve this.

Comment: add same android-support-v4.jar file in project and library.
you can copy android-support-v4.jar from lib project and replace your current project android-support-v4.jar file.

Comment: You mean like, Copy it from Android Private Libraries and paste it in Referenced Libraries.

Comment: Sorry Imtiyaz. I couldn't get u clearly and i couldn't able to solve it. Initially i added 'map_lib' in my project. Then i added the 'google_play_services_lib'. When i added the second lib my R.java file is missing and gives Jar mismatch error in Console. How to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

First import both library properly. Then go properties->java buildpath then check wether your library is checked or not. then clean your project.

Comment: Thanks iffran. I added both libraries like Properties>Android>library>add. When i add the second library my R.java file is missing. Is it right way to do i?

Comment: check with your xml file. I think the problem is in xml design else delete the bin and gen folder then again add the library then clean the project. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can use any number of library files in our projects. If any mistakes in xml files R.java won't created. Try to check it.